# Angular | Error response coming late using httpInterceptor

Tags: angular, ngxs

I am facing an issue with handling errors from an API. The problem is that I recieve an error but it is delayed and by the time response arrives my code gets executed and I get undefined in the object where I'm storing the error object. Below is my error interceptor:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class HttpErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private injector: Injector) { }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request)
      .pipe(catchError(error => this.handleError(error)));
  }

  handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    let errorMessage = '';
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      // client-side error
      errorMessage = `Error: ${error.error.message}`;
    } else {
      // server-side error
      errorMessage = `Error Code: ${error.status}\nMessage: ${error.message}`;
    }
    return throwError(error.error);
  }
}
```

Below is the code from state.ts file for an action:

```
@Action(PutItem)
  putItem({ patchState, getState }: StateContext<ItemStateModel>, { payload }: PutItem) {
    this._item.putItemAPI(payload).pipe(take(1)).subscribe(res => {
      const state = getState();
      patchState({
        ...state,
        itemVersion: res['version']
      });
    },
      error => {
      const state = getState();
      patchState({
          ...state,
          error: error,
      });
    });
  }
```

Below is my component.ts file where I'm calling the action

```
this._store.dispatch(
          new PutItem(itemObj)
        ).pipe(take(1)).subscribe(res => {
            console.log(res[0]['items']['error'])
        });
```

On the click of button, the above action is dispatched and I get an error from API. But the very first time I get null in the console and when I click on the button again then I get the correct error message.
It seems to me that error arrives late and my action gets completed before that. 
How can I make it wait for the error to arrive? My other code works fine for the success case though.

Please let me know if I've missed any information which is required.

Comment: You're missunderstanding action handlers, you shouldn't do subscriptions inside action handlers, NGXS doesn't work like that! Please, refer to the documentation regarding action handlers, it's a big topic.

Comment: thanks for the reply but what could be the issue that action dispatch completes before the error part in state.ts file?

Comment: Read the documentation please :)